# Count all elements in a tree that meet a condition using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of `Person` objects. Each Person has a list of Persons as a property. Here's the class.

```
 public class Person
 {       
     public List<Person> Team { get; set; }
     public string Status {get; set;}
 }
```

So each person has a parent, a list of children, and a status.

I need to count the number of times the status equals `"X"` or `"Y"` in a given person's tree. I was told I could use the `.Aggregate()` function, but I'm not sure how I would do that.

For example, if a Person had a list of 3 people all with status `"X"` and each of those people had lists of 3 people, 2 with status `"X"` and 1 with status `"Z"`, that would be 12 people total and the count of `"X"` would be 9.

Comment: In case of a tree (which is a kind of recursive data structure), you should consider using recursive methods to navigate through it. Linq is more suitable for sequential structures, or to reach a specific depth in a tree (which in fact is a kind of sequential navigation).

Comment: Is your graph cyclic?

Comment: @Servy assuming the OP used the term "tree" correctly, then trees are acyclic by definition.

Comment: @dcastro Enough people use that term incorrectly that I felt it merited verifying that assumption.  But yes, you are correct.

Comment: @Servy fair enough, after a while you learn to validate those assumptions :)

Answer (score 4):

You could recursively "flatten" your tree, like this for example (using a post-fix iterator):

```
public class Person
{
    public List<Person> Team { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Person> Flatten()
    {
        yield return this;

        foreach (var person in Team)
            foreach (var child in person.Flatten())
                yield return child;
    } 
}
```

And then, using a "root" person, you could do this:

```
var count = person.Flatten().Count(p => p.Status == "X" || p.Status == "Y");
```

If you had a collection of people, you could combine `SelectMany` with `Flatten`.

```
people.SelectMany(p => p.Flatten()).Count(...)
```